# HPLIP spitting out raw data when I attempt to print

Tags: printing

We got a new printer (HP m1212nf) as it was stated on the hplip site to be supported.

Printer has been tested in windows so we know it works as well as it's network setup.

Current system I am attempting to set this network printer up on is Debian 6 squeeze fully up to date. I downloaded the newest HPLIP from their site.  Ran the .run file and followed directions.  Installed the prerequisites and ran and hp-check to make sure all was included.

hp-setup was ran where I added the printer.  I tried a test page and it came out as raw pdf data.  I then followed with a simple few words from gedit.  Same thing, pages of rubbish.  Tried a PDF file and I got 6 pages of junk(raw pdf).

Not exactly sure what to do in this situation.  My system does connect, but it seems the printing is getting distorted someplace.  any ideaS?

Comment: Assuming you use `cups`, have you looked at the logs in `/var/log/cups/`?

Comment: I've had similar behavior with some HP printers. Try to update the hplip package on your system and then, via CUPS (go to `locahlost:631` in browser), re-add the printer with (as a new one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost certain me restarting cups resolved this issue as well as making sure that the printer was in cups config http://127.0.0.1:631/

Thanks all